# How do I show R is regular?

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers

How do I prove that R (the reals) are a regular space?

This means I need to show that given any nonempty closed set F and any point x that does not belong to F, there exists a neighborhood U of x and a neighborhood V of F that are disjoint.

I can see how this is obviously true intuitively but I need help writing a rigorous proof for it.

Comment: Alternatively, show that every open neighbourhood of $x$ contains a closed neighbourhood of $x$. You know how the neighbourhoods of $x$ look in $\mathbb{R}$, so it's easy.

Comment: Well I can see intuitively why that would be true but how could I rigorously show that an open interval in R contains a closed neighborhood in R around x?

Comment: Say the open interval contains $(x-\varepsilon, x+ \varepsilon)$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$. You need to show that there is a $\delta > 0$ with $[x-\delta,x+\delta] \subset (x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)$. No problem doing that, I suppose.

Comment: Let δ =  ε/2?  Then for any ε, [x−ε/2,x+ε/2]⊂(x−ε,x+ε) and so for every open interval this is true.  Would that prove it?

Comment: For example. Any $0 < \delta < \varepsilon$ does it, $\varepsilon/2$ is probably the most often used one.

Answer (score 0):

It's a metric space, so it's even normal. The open sets are
$$\{x\in\mathbb R\mid\inf_{y\in F_1} d(x,y)<\inf_{y\in F_2} d(x,y)\}\text{ and }\{x\in\mathbb R\mid\inf_{y\in F_1} d(x,y)>\inf_{y\in F_2} d(x,y)\}$$